# Build a Java application with HTML, CSS and JS for it's UI design

Tags: javascript, java, css, sql, html

I've been into web development for a while, and JS has really proven worthy. But this time, I want to build a desktop app (with SQLITE). I want the app to be built in Java, but I'm afraid the design might not be what I want (compared to what I can do with HTML and CSS).

My question is: 
Is it possible to build use HTML, CSS (bootstrap) and JS for the UI design, and still have it as a Java Application? In other words, can I build the interface with HTML and CSS, add some JavaScript events, and still deploy the app as a desktop app?

And PS, if you can suggest any other language that will be suitable for the purpose (database connection with no internet; desktop application; JavaScript effects; beautiful design like Bootstrap tools), I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: HTML, JS, and CSS are designed for web browsers, although they can work with other types of applications such as pdf documents.  However, you say you want to build a desktop application.  That often means something that runs on it's own, without a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use an MVC framework like Spring.

https://spring.io/

Comment: could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible using [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/). There are more solutions out there, but this is what I'm working with.

There's also [Wicket Bootstrap](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap) which additionally includes Bootstrap components.